# Implementing plugin in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, plugins, phonegap-plugins

I am developing android mobile application using phonegap.I want to implement “ContactPicker plugin“ from github webstie.For implement plugin I refered below article

"https://github.com/sconover/phonegap-android-plugin-examples"

In above article they explained the path of plugin, But on my machine I did not find the path

"src/com/phonegap/HelloWorldPlugin/HelloWorldPlugin.java” In my plugin. Also I was unable to get the file HelloWorldPlugin.java

I tried to install plugin using command line tool but not sure its installed or not.

I am unable to use this plugin in my phonegap application. I am stuckup with very basic step of copying files and using the same in phonegap.

Comment: have you create the path and plugin file?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use old plugins, this one is about four years old. A lot of things changes since 2010.

Use the original cordova plugin: [org.apache.cordova.contacts](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.contacts)

Comment: I checked given link. I want to synchronize phonebook contacts into my application. SO which plug-in should I use? In the article they have suggested to install plugin using CLI. I tried installing plugin using CLI. Please refer link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856287/phonegap-unable-to-install-plugins-using-plugman
But I am not able to understand whether plugin is installed or not on my machine.